# Are rune bonuses stacked or are they replaced?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've recently purchased a nice set of 6 [Superior Runes of Scavenging](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Rune_of_Scavenging#Superior_Rune_of_Scavenging) for my flamethrower guardian build. However, I was wondering something. At 1 rune worn I get +28 condition damage, at 3 runes I get +55 condition damage and at 5 runes I get +100 condition damage. Do those bonuses stack (i.e. would I get +183 condition damage), or is only the last one applied (i.e. would I get +100 condition damage)?

Similarly, would I get +35% magic find or +15% magic find?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - the statistics provided by runes do stack. In the instance you're referring to with the Superior Runes of Scavenging, having six of these runes in your gear would apply *all* of the bonuses stated on the runes;

- (1): +28  Condition Damage
- (2): +7%  Magic find
- (3): +55  Condition Damage
- (4): +13%  Magic find
- (5): +100  Condition Damage
- (6): +15%  Magic find; Increased Gold from Monsters

With all six runes, this would give you a total of 183 condition damage and 35% bonus to magic and gold finding.

This is detailed on the [Guild Wars 2 wiki page for Runes](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Rune#Stacking).